# Switch case match with string

Tags: javascript

```
function getFieldType(value){
    var type = "";
    switch(value){
        case "TEXT_BOX":
            type=FieldTypeEnum.TEXT_BOX;
            break;
        case "PASSWORD":
            type=FieldTypeEnum.PASSWORD;
            break;
        case "CHECK_BOX":
            type=FieldTypeEnum.CHECK_BOX;
            break;
        case "RADIO_BUTTON":
            type=FieldTypeEnum.RADIO_BUTTON;
            break;
        case "DROP_DOWN":
            type=FieldTypeEnum.DROP_DOWN;
            break;
        case "SEARCH_CARD_BOX":
            type=FieldTypeEnum.SEARCH_CARD_BOX;
            break;        
        case "STATE_DROP_DOWN":
            type=FieldTypeEnum.STATE_DROP_DOWN;
            break;
        case "ID_DROP_DOWN":
            type=FieldTypeEnum.ID_DROP_DOWN;
            break;
        case "GENDER_DROP_DOWN":
            type = FieldTypeEnum.GENDER_DROP_DOWN;
            break;
        default:
            type = "";
    }

    return type;
}
```

I want to combined three drop down box `(STATE_DROP_DOWN, ID_DROP_DOWN, GENDER_DROP_DOWN)`into one .
Means I want something like below :

```
case String.endwith("_DROP_DOWN"):
     type=FieldTypeEnum.ID_DROP_DOWN;
     break;
```

Is it possible in JavaScript? If yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, in a javascript switch/case statement you can compare for string equality (which evaluates to true or false) or more complex statements which just as when testing for string equality, also evaluate to true or false (e.g. `String.endwith("_DROP_DOWN")`). However personally I would prefer the following:

```
STATE_DROP_DOWN:
  // intentional fall through
ID_DROP_DOWN:
  // intentional fall through 
GENDER_DROP_DOWN:
  //.. do your stuff
  break;
```

I believe this way it is more clearly through which switch case you are falling in a certain situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a ternary operator in the case, and test if it ends with `"DROP_DOWN"` return `value` otherwise blank string.

```
switch(value){
    case value.endsWith("_DROP_DOWN") ? value : '' {
     type=FieldTypeEnum.ID_DROP_DOWN;
     break;
 }
}
```